# Recomputing footprints on old satellite imagery

Tags: arcgis-10.0, imagery, footprint

I am trying to create an image service out of some 1976 satellite imagery. But first I need to get all of the no data cells out of my mosaic dataset. I have tried to recompute the footprints on my mosaic dataset in ArcMap and only some of the footprints are changing on the tiles. I don't understand why this is happening, and I am not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Stating *how* you tried to compute the footprints might give readers useful clues to help you out.

Comment: I used the Build footprints (data management) tool in ArcMap.

Comment: Ah!  New tool.  I added a tag to let people know.

Comment: I used the Define Mosaic Dataset NoData tool ( Data Management) in ArcMap it did take the black out. Then I color balanced the mosaic dataset with the color balance tool (data management)but it doesn't look as smooth as it did before I took the original no Data cells out.